# Can we reset value of ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() if it is denied earlier ?

Tags: ios, abaddressbook

Im using ABAddressBook currently in my application. Im wondering whether if we could reset the value of ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() if it is denied in earlier time ?

This should obviously done by programmatically and not by manually going into settings and changing the permission.

Any help regarding this will be appreciated !

Comment: No, you can just show alert to user, notify him that a certain permission is denied and to proceed with app you have to enable it from settings.

Comment: You mean to say that , if user wants to change the permission then he/she must go to settings. 

We just can show him/her alert. @IrfanGul

Comment: exactly! there is no other way. due to security and privacy concerns by apple.